# Is there a point in chosing quest locations in Monster Girl Quest out of order?

Tags: monster-girl-quest

During the playthrough of the Monster Girl Quest (もんむす くえすと) series, you can often pick your next play/quest location from a map. They are clearly marked with minimum levels suggested for each, and if you stick to that order, the game makes sure you gain enough XP to be ready for the next one in order.

Now, you *can* pick them out of order as well, but the one time I tried I couldn't see much of a difference in the leveling speed, rewards or anything else really.

So is there even any point in trying to complete the harder challenges first? Does the game reward - or punish - you for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special rewards for completing anything out of order, but there are rewards for revisiting areas and talking to different people in areas you have cleared before leaving.  Look up "[Hero's Proof](http://monstergirlquest.wikia.com/wiki/Hero%E2%80%99s_Proof)" for details.  More a completionist thing than any real in game benefits, up to part two that is.  No word yet on if part three will make use of it in some way that I know of.  Sources: playing the game, [Monster Girl Quest Wiki](http://monstergirlquest.wikia.com/wiki/).

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include the link to the relevant page in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Part 3 has an Achievement that is earned by only playing the necessary stages and skipping everywhere else.

It can get very difficult unless you are playing Ex-Mode (unlocked with completion of part 3).

My original saves were on my old PC and by the time I got around to playing again Part 3 was out so I played it and beat it before combining it with Parts 1 and 2-still kept ex mode, so that is a possibility if you do not have a previous completed save to work from.